# If $A$ singular, then there is some invertible $B$ such that $BA$ is nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have long been studying a claim my professor made yesterday, and I am very stuck. I have tried to perform a singular value decomposition, but I have gotten nowhere. Here is the problem: given a singular matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, show that there exists an invertible matrix $B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that the matrix $BA$ is nilpotent.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Singular value decomposition should work. You have $PAQ=D$ where $D$ is a matrix with $2$ blocks $I_r$ and a zero matrix. Find $S$ such that $SPAQ=SD=N$ where $N$ is nilpotent. Finally $QSPA=QNQ^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

First, as others have noted, you need to decompose $A$ using a suitable matrix factorization. The one proposed by @user1551 (who unfortunately deleted his comment) is the most suitable: there are nonsingular matrices $C,D$ such that $A=C(I_r\oplus 0_{n-r})D$, where $r=\operatorname{rank}(A)$. In fact this factorization is a simple consequence of Gaussian elimination. Now, we can choose $B=D^{-1}EC^{-1}$, such that $E$ is nonsingular, and $E(I_r \oplus 0_{n-r}) = N$ is nilpotent. Because $BA = D^{-1}ND$, it follows that $BA$ is similar to a nilpotent matrix, hence nilpotent itself. So the real meat of the question is to indeed figure out what $E$ is.

Let us define and partition $E$ conformally as
$$
E = \begin{pmatrix}N_r & -P\\Q & I_{n-r}\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $N_r$ is a nilpotent matrix, then
$$
BA = \begin{pmatrix}N_r & 0\\Q & 0_{n-r}\end{pmatrix},
$$
and this matrix is clearly nilpotent. What is left to do is determine $N_r, P$ and $Q$ such that $E$ is nonsingular.

To this end, the determinant of $E$ is
$$
\det E=\det(N_r + PQ),
$$
using the Schur complement, so $E$ is nonsingular iff $N_r + PQ$ is nonsingular. Let us take $N_r$ to be the shift matrix (ones on the superdiagonal and zeros everywhere else). Then choosing $P$ such that its $(r,1)$-th entry is $1$ and the rest zero, and $Q$ has its $(1,1)$-th entry equal to $1$ and the rest zero, then $N_r + PQ$ becomes a cyclic permutation matrix, hence invertible.

Comment: You can get $N$ from $I_r \oplus 0_{n-r}$ ($r<n$) by moving the last row of zeros to the first row

Comment: @Lozenges Yes you're right. I focused too much on characterizing all of the matrices that work.